# does java connectionpooled.close() will close the db session

Tags: java, connection-pooling

if the close of javax.sql.connectionpooled connection,it will not leave any INACTIVE SESSION in Database.in my case i can see many INACTIVE SESSIONS in DB(oracle), how to close it,programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a javax.sql.PooledConnection implementation (which should not be used by you, but only by a connectionpool), or a Connection obtained from a connection pool?

If the first: closing a PooledConnection should close the physical connection, if the second: closing a (logical) connection obtained from the connectionpool should leave the physical connection open, because that is the whole point of the connectionpool.

Things get a bit more complicated when you abuse various layers of datasource which each do their own connectionpooling.